# Receiving NoClassDefFoundError when invoking generated serializer() method

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization, kotlinx

I’m getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to invoke the `Foo.serializer()` method on a `@Serializable` class.

Here's my test case:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Foo(val data: String)

val jsonString = json.stringify(
  Foo.serializer(), // <= Error happens here
  Foo(data = "foo")
)
```

Attempting to run the code results in the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlinx.serialization.internal.SerialClassDescImpl.<init>(java.lang.String, kotlinx.serialization.internal.GeneratedSerializer, int)'
    at com.example.Foo$$serializer.<clinit>(Foo.kt:7)
    at com.example.Foo$Companion.serializer(Foo.kt)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the result of version mismatches between Kotlin and Kotlinx.serialization, as they are relatively tightly coupled. In my case I was using Kotlin 1.3.71 and kotlinx.serialization 0.14.0, so the solution was to upgrade kotlinx.serialization to 0.20.0.

Comment: In my case I had the same issue, to fix it I set the Kotlin version and the kotlinx.serialization version to "1.3.70"

Comment: This seems to fix for some folks, but the issue still exists even after using 1.3.72 and 0.20.0.

Make sure to generate a clean build (as a workaround for now) - https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/576#issuecomment-637020824

Comment: awesome， upgrade kotlinx.serialization to 0.20.0 and  Kotlin 1.3.71 fix my problem